# Azure API Gateway and Web Apps - how to serve CSS, JS and images?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-api-management, api-gateway

I have a website that serves regular sites using ASP.NET MVC, and also acts as an API which has resources that return JSON.

I've chosen to "hide" this website/API behind an Azure API Gateway, because of all the features that the gateway offers.

I am facing a challenge when having to serve images, javascript and CSS.

The gateway has a base url: api.mysite.com

The website/API has the following API URL suffix: api.mysite.com/wixplugin

When accessing a page through the API, e.g:

api.mysite.com/wixplugin/landingpage

that page tries to serve content from the API base URL, e.g:  api.mysite.com/Scripts/jquery.js

The problem is, that the API gateway does not know that it should actually fetch content from the website/API.

What can I do to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Look into policies to rewrite urls in responses that your website produces so that they point to your gateway host. Here is a policy designed just for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#MaskURLSContent. Or you could use more generic find-and-replace policy.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem hosting web service behind Azure API Management (APIM).

I solve it by changing the URL in my frontend section of APIM from / to /*. And also adding `<redirect-content-urls />` in the outbound policy.